# Django makemigrations is ignoring keys with underscore for CharField

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I'm currently working on a chat application in Django and tried to set up a model for text messages. When I create the model with *python manage.py* ***makemigrations*** the fields msg_to and msg_from are ignored and won't appear in the SQLite database after ***python manage.py migrate***. When I change them to msg from and msg to they appear. Can anyone proof this behavior or explain to me why this is happening?

```
class Chat_message(models.Model):
        msg_from = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
        msg_to = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
        msg = models.TextField()
        timestamp_sent = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
        timestamp_read = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you please mention Django's version?

Comment: Can you show us migration that pops out when you change field names